# Fat Free Framework: how create dynamic menu with submenu

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have this table

```
id  children    voce    alias   pubblicato
11  NULL    Chi Siamo   chi-siamo   1
12  11  Chi Siamo - Sub chi-siamo-sub   1
```

So the id 12 is children (submenu) of 11.

With this block i can print the first level of a menu

```
<repeat group="{{ @result }}" key="{{ @ikey }}" value="{{ @voce }}">
<li><a href="{{ @ABSOLUTE_PATH }}/{{ trim(@voce.alias) }}">{{ trim(@voce.voce) }}</a></li>
</repeat>
```

(result is result of query SQL).

Of course i need to obtain that in my scheme menu will be (pseudo // bootstrap html code)

```
<li><a href="#">ID 11 menu</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Id 12 menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, in (very!) pseudo code

```
   if (children is not null) {
      don't echo </li>
      echo <ul class="dropdown">
      echo voce where children == parent
   }
```

Thank you very much.

PS If you think that my table need to be edit, don't worry, tell me your best solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did this the following way:

```
    // load page tree
        $pages = $model->find();
        $pageTree = array();
        $pagesByID = array();
        foreach($pages as $index => $page)
            $pagesByID[$page->_id] = $page->cast();
        // reorder to tree
        foreach ($pagesByID as &$value)
            if ($parent = $value['pid'])
                $pagesByID[$parent]['childs'][] = &$value;
            else
                $pageTree[] = &$value;
```

$pageTree is now a multi-dimensional array, with child keys, if that page has some childs.

Comment: Thank you!
But how did you print the menu//submenu, starting from that array and using f3 <repeat> template?

Thank you very much